# WP7: Data Binding to MainViewModel from within a DataTemplate

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, windows-phone-7, expression-blend

Within a WP7 project, I need to data-bind controls within DataTemplates (a Pivot TitleTemplate, for example) to top-level items on the MainViewModel. How can this be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for WP7 version as well as Silverlight 4. Use an element binding to the view itself (or any named node higher up the visual tree) and refer to the DataContext.*elementName* in the binding.

e.g.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=myViewName, Path=DataContext.SomeTitleProperty}"/>
```